# Java Jlist Scrollbar

Tags: java, swing

In a JList with a scrollpane. I have assigned a default selection value.
On click of a reset button I'm assigning the default value.
It works fine for when there are less values.
But when there are many values when I press reset the default value gets selected, but is not focused. I remain at the end of the scrollbar and not at the beginning where the scrollbar begins because the default value is the first value. Can anyone please help me with this.

Comment: What `ListModel`? How are you clearing it?

Answer (score 1):

```
JList.ensureIndexIsVisible(int index)
```

Comment: No its a normal JList..im reseting it using the method Setselectionindex(0).

Comment: No its a normal JList. Im reseting using the method setselectionindex(0)

Comment: The Jlist is getting Reset but the scrollbar is not.

Comment: did you even try what i said? That fixes your problem.

Comment: Yup i tried it. that didn do it actually. the solution was to resert the scrollpane also. scrollpane.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(0);

Comment: @user696266 it that's needed, something is wrong with your code which needs to be fixed